# How to integrate this integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having trouble solving this (note: we have not studied it yet nor was Google of any help)

$$\int e^{x^x}\, dx$$

Comment: I do not think that you can solve it.

Comment: Did you find this in some book or make it up yourself? $x^x$ normally renders integrals very hard to evaluate.

Comment: Unless you integrate with respect to $e$, which the question doesn't specify; then it's just $\frac{e^{x^x+1}}{x^x + 1}$. ;)

Comment: @MGA actually I would say, your integration for $de$ is wrong. $de=0$, therefore interpreted as a reimann sum this evaluates to $0$.

Comment: @Sabyashachi I meant with respect to $e$, I was just kidding.

Comment: @MGA i came across it while i was going through nust (a university here in Pakistan) admission test sample !

Comment: The anti-derivative of $x^x$ can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions, which makes it very unlikely that your integral can be evaluated (at least in the way that you're probably expecting).

Comment: Unless you mean $(e^x)^x$, I must agree with the other answers.

Comment: And what did the admission test sample actually say?  Evaluate the indefinite integral?  Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) and [Risch's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), this primitive cannot be expressed in terms of [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). Nor are there any [special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_special_functions_and_eponyms) that I know of which can help express it either (by using some substitution, for instance). Not even the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks seems like the answer is supposed to this bad boy cant be solved!!

Comment: odd if i apply limits (e.g. 1-2) the calculator seems to be able to output an answer? if this was not possible that shouldn't happen right?

Comment: Neither Mathematica, nor Mapple, nor Maxima are able to come up with a closed form solution for any sort of limits.

Comment: Or are you referring to numeric integration ? All definite integrals can be computed numerically, but not all possess a symbolic expression.

Comment: why is that? cause calculators are programmed !! they do nt evaluate the the expressions!!

Comment: An indefinite integral, like the one in your question, is not a number, but a function. The fact that a primitive function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary ones does not automatically mean that a definite integral associated with it does not possess a closed form expression. An obvious example is the [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), whose [definite integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) between $\pm\infty$ is $\sqrt\pi$. Now, your function does not belong to any of the two categories mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

$\int e^{x^x}~dx=\int\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{mx}}{m!}dx$

Then apply the approach similar to [Series Expansion Of An Integral.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716324) and you will finally find that

$\int e^{x^x}~dx=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}m^nx^n(\ln x)^k}{m!k!(n+1)^{n-k+1}}+C$